# grouping, counting by time and then sorting within group using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `dataframe` -

```
                 EventID    Institution_Name
TimeCreated     
2021-03-22 15:34:46 40  H1
2021-03-22 18:17:19 40  H2
2021-03-22 20:37:47 40  H2
2021-03-22 20:40:20 40  H2
2021-03-22 21:37:32 40  H2
2021-03-22 22:16:32 40  H2
2021-03-22 23:19:49 40  H2
2021-03-22 23:26:40 40  H2
2021-03-23 00:26:03 40  H3
2021-03-23 01:25:43 40  H4
2021-03-23 04:00:24 40  H5
2021-03-23 13:09:42 40  H6
2021-03-23 13:13:23 40  H1
2021-03-23 15:49:33 40  H7
2021-03-23 17:22:30 40  H8
2021-03-23 17:22:37 40  H8
2021-03-23 17:23:49 40  H9
2021-03-23 18:19:56 40  H2
2021-03-23 18:22:14 40  H2
2021-03-23 18:52:36 40  H10
```

I want to count number of events for each institution each day and sort the count in a descending order while maintaining the days in ascending order.
eg. the final result would look something like this -

```
TimeCreated     Institution_Name EventID_count
2021-03-22       H2                7
2021-03-22       H1                1
....
2021-03-23       H2                2
and so on
```

I am using the following -

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D'), 'Institution_Name'])
grouper['EventID'].count().reset_index().sort_values(['TimeCreated'],ascending=True).sort_values('EventID', ascending=False).head(5)

 but this does not give the desired result.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Group by 2 columns

```py
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='TimeCreated', freq='1D'), 'Institution_Name'])

grouper = grouper.count().groupby('TimeCreated', group_keys=False)
```

2. Sort the elements(the count) in each group of date

```py
grouper_count_desc = grouper.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='EventID', ascending=False))
```

```
In[65]: grouper_count_desc
Out[65]: 
                              EventID
TimeCreated Institution_Name         
2021-03-22  H2                      7
            H1                      1
2021-03-23  H2                      2
            H8                      2
            H1                      1
            H10                     1
            H3                      1
            H4                      1
            H5                      1
            H6                      1
            H7                      1
            H9                      1
```

3. Sort the groups of date. The order of elements in each group wouldn't change

```py
grouper_date_asc = grouper_count_desc.sort_values(by='TimeCreated', ascending=True)
```

```
In[70]: grouper_date_desc = grouper_count_desc.sort_values(by='TimeCreated', ascending=False) # to show result, I used descending
In[71]: grouper_date_desc
Out[71]: 
                              EventID
TimeCreated Institution_Name         
2021-03-23  H2                      2
            H8                      2
            H1                      1
            H10                     1
            H3                      1
            H4                      1
            H5                      1
            H6                      1
            H7                      1
            H9                      1
2021-03-22  H2                      7
            H1                      1
```

4. Reset index and show result

```py
print(grouper_date_asc.reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to get the date for grouping.  Aggregate count by [`.GroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) and then sort columns, as follows:

```
(df.groupby([df['TimeCreated'].dt.normalize(),
             'Institution_Name'])
   .agg(EventID_count=('EventID', 'count'))
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
)
```

If your `TimeCreated` is an index, you can use `df.index.normalize()`, as follows:

```
(df.groupby([df.index.normalize(),
             'Institution_Name'])
   .agg(EvenetID_count=('EventID', 'count'))
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
)
```

**Result:**

```
   TimeCreated Institution_Name  EventID_count
0   2021-03-22               H2              7
1   2021-03-22               H1              1
2   2021-03-23               H9              1
3   2021-03-23               H8              2
4   2021-03-23               H7              1
5   2021-03-23               H6              1
6   2021-03-23               H5              1
7   2021-03-23               H4              1
8   2021-03-23               H3              1
9   2021-03-23               H2              2
10  2021-03-23              H10              1
11  2021-03-23               H1              1
```

Your code is actually quite close (for the case `TimeCreated` is an index), just need to change the way you sort the columns, as follows:

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D'), 'Institution_Name'])
grouper['EventID'].count().reset_index().sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True)
```

The result of these codes is the same as above, except that the column name for `EventID` remains as `EventID` instead of `EventID_count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
(df.groupby([df['TimeCreated'].dt.floor('d'),
             'Institution_Name'])
 [['EventID']].count()
 .add_suffix('_count')
 .sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False])
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   TimeCreated Institution_Name  EventID_count
0   2021-03-22               H2              7
1   2021-03-22               H1              1
2   2021-03-23               H9              1
3   2021-03-23               H8              2
4   2021-03-23               H7              1
5   2021-03-23               H6              1
6   2021-03-23               H5              1
7   2021-03-23               H4              1
8   2021-03-23               H3              1
9   2021-03-23               H2              2
10  2021-03-23              H10              1
11  2021-03-23               H1              1
```

Your initial attempt did not work as Grouper did not know where to find your Dates (it is using by default the index). Here are two ways to fix it.

define the column name:

```
(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D', key='TimeCreated'),
             'Institution_Name'])
   [['EventID']].count()
   .add_suffix('_count')
   .sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False])
   .reset_index()
)
```

use the column as index:

```
(df.set_index('TimeCreated')
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1D'),
             'Institution_Name'])
   [['EventID']].count()
   .add_suffix('_count')
   .sort_values(['TimeCreated', 'Institution_Name'], ascending=[True, False])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: EventID_count should be in descending order while the date should be ascending order at the same time. Look at my output.